# custom python package installation with setup.py

Tags: python, installation, setuptools, setup.py

I would like to install a python package (third party package written with cython for some numerical calculations).
My previous experience (which were successfully) is that, I only need to perform following command:

```
python setup.py install --prefix="/destination/path/"
```

Then, I would expect an additional folder as /destination/path/package
so, I can do

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/destination/path/
```

So, I can finally import the package normally in python script.

However, it seems that the default behavior of setup.py (I am using anaconda python3.7) changed. When I use the same (first) command, I encounter an error as:

```
Checking .pth file support in /destination/path//lib/python3.7/site-packages/

/path/to/python -E -c pass

TEST FAILED: /destination/path/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ does NOT support .pth files
error: bad install directory or PYTHONPATH

You are attempting to install a package to a directory that is not
on PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from.  The
installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

/destination/path/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
```

Could someone explain to me what happened and how can I fix this error?

Thank you very much in advance.

Best,

Greg

Comment: `/destination/path//lib/python3.7/site-packages/` this isn't a valid path, was that a copy paste issue or actually part of the error?

Comment: @JordanSimba: No, that is not the real path, I replaced a long path-prefix with the "/destination/path/"

Comment: The double slash... no way of telling if some automated process did that